# Scrapy - spider with AJAX pagination

Tags: ajax, scrapy

Been going through many related questions without finding a clear answer to this fairly common scraping question.

I am trying to scrape a typical real estate site.

(start_url = http://www.metrocuadrado.com/web/buscarFiltros/bogota-apartamento-venta).

Sixteen ads per (list) page. Next (list) page shows the next 16 ads, and gets its content through AJAX (pressing a "next page" button).

The detailed item-info I need is obtained on the specific ad page, one level deeper, following the links to the ads. This info is URL-based, not AJAX.

I've been trying to figure out a solution with CrawlSpider and Selenium, but am confused about how to combine the rules and callbacks. Any advice (a general structure) would be so welcome !

Comment: Here is an idea: inspect the **Network** tab in your browser, look for the requests that grab the content you want and then replay them with Scrapy.

Comment: Thanks Elias. Already followed the idea but ran into the following problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665388/using-the-browsers-xhr-log-to-recreate-an-ajax-request